# Removing character(s) from multiple file names

Tags: bash

I have several hundred files that I need to remove specific characters from - in this case zeroes in multiples. My file names look like this:

```
filename.R10001.out
filename.R10002.out
....
filename.R10010.out
filename.R10011.out
```

I want to replace all the leading zeroes before the file numbers with an underscore, so that I end up with:

```
filename.R1_1.out
filename.R1_2.out
....
filename.R1_10.out
filename.R1_11.out
```

I have tried a couple other solutions, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with the number of zeroes changing or writing a similar line a bunch of times with different numbers.

```
for f in ./*; do mv "$f" "${f%R1*1}.out" ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for f in ./* ; do
  newname=$(echo "$f" | sed "s/0\{2,10\}/_/g")
  echo mv "$f" "$newname"
done
```

**Explanation:**

Loop all files in the current directory, create the $newname variable by replacing 2 or more (supposing until 10 **{2,10}**) occurrences of 0 with _.
Test it and if you like it remove the echo.

**Edit after suggestion in comment**

```
for f in ./* ; do
   newname=$(echo "$f" | sed "s/0\{2,\}/_/g")
   echo mv "$f" "$newname"
done
```

Comment: If you don't want to limit to 10, you can use `\{2,\}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bash, a Regular Expression can do the filename change:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Enable Bash Extended Globbing
shopt -s extglob

# Iterate files matching the Extended Globbing
for f in ./*.R[[:digit:]]+(0)+([[:digit:]]).out; do
  # If f is a regular file AND matches the RegEx
  if [[ -f "$f" && "$f" =~ (.*\.R[[:digit:]])0*([[:digit:]]+.*) ]]; then
    # Rename the file using RegEx's captured groups
    mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Perl-based [`rename`](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) tool:

```
$ rename -n 's/0+/_/' *.out
'filename.R10001.out' would be renamed to 'filename.R1_1.out'
'filename.R10002.out' would be renamed to 'filename.R1_2.out'
'filename.R10010.out' would be renamed to 'filename.R1_10.out'
'filename.R10011.out' would be renamed to 'filename.R1_11.out'
```

If the output looks correct, you can drop the `-n` parameter and actually rename.

---

Alternatively, with extended globs (still assuming that replacing the first occurrence of zeroes is what we want to replace):

```sh
for f in ./*.out; do echo mv "$f" "${f/+(0)/_}"; done
```

This requires `shopt -s extglob` to be set. Drop the `echo` when the commands look right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sed only solution:

```
$ ls filename.* | sed 's/\(.*R1\)\(0*\)\([0-9].*\)/mv & \1_\3/'  
mv filename.R10001.out filename.R1_1.out
mv filename.R10002.out filename.R1_2.out
mv filename.R10010.out filename.R1_10.out
mv filename.R10011.out filename.R1_11.out
```

Following Benjamin's lead, you can review the above output first to see if you are happy with the results.  To execute the commands, you can pipe the output to bash as follows:

```
$ ls filename.* | sed 's/\(.*R1\)\(0*\)\([0-9].*\)/mv & \1_\3/'   | bash
```